# Setup compiler for Mac arm for Qt 5.15

Tags: macos, qt, arm, incompatibility

Just after I have installed Qt 5.15 on Mac mini with M1 processor I got issues with compiler. I'm just starting to learn Mac. Absolutely have no idea how to fix it. I have installed Xcode 14 with tools also. My goal is to build ARM and x86_x64 compatible app from Qt 5.15 project. That was done before on x64 machine with Xcode 11.7. It seems it's impossible to run this version in newer architecture. Now I need to set environment to build both ARM and x86_x64
[Errors in Qt kits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46hng.jpg)

I think there some deal with rosetta, but I don't understand how do I add compatible compiler for Qt 5.15

Comment: How did you install qt?  Are you attempting to build qt?  Have you looked at the Homebrew formula?  There are many issues with building open-source qt 5.15 on arm64 macOS.  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/466ffd6a1194bf049b5508f202bd8c242861b1d8/Formula/qt@5.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup `xcode-select` as [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/macos.html) says. Run this in terminal:

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Than re-open Qt creator and check kits and make sure that compiler was found.